# Can I submit an iOS app to the Mac App store?

Tags: macos, app-store

I've created an iOS app that supports multiple resolutions and I'd like to submit it to the Mac App store. Can I submit the IPA to the Mac App store?

More info:
I have an iOS account that I paid $99 for. Do I also have to buy another account? I'm not using XCode.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: What are you talking about? It's a legitimate question. If you can compile to LLVM it should be possible to export to a Mac desktop app. Look up bitcode.

Answer (score 4):

No. OS X does not have UIKit as a native framework, so it simply won't run. You could look into [The Chameleon Project](http://chameleonproject.org/) from The IconFactory, which attempts to create a UIKit API compatible framework for the desktop.

If you manage to get your application into an OS X ready state, you'll need a Mac Developer account to submit it to the Mac App Store. Signup is basically identical to the signup for an iOS account, and costs the same. See developer.apple.com for more.

Comment: ok. do you know if UIKit will be included in OSX Lion? this is why i ask, http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/full-screen.html, http://www.apple.com/macosx/whats-new/app-store.html

Comment: As far as I know, it will never be. There are too many touch related events in UIKit that have no reasonable desktop analogue.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
It appears it will be possible, http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/air_marketplace_faq.html

Quote, ...There are now several app stores on desktops, mobile devices and tablets that service AIR developers including Apple App Store, Android Market, BlackBerry App World, Intel AppUp center, Samsung Apps, and Toshiba App Place...